# Connecting ASP.net form with access database 2015 and publishing asp.net website on local domain controlled server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to create a simple web page that will interact with a Microsoft access 2015 database. I would prefer to use asp.net instead of basic html as I am more familiar with this. How can I connect ASP.net form  with access database 2015. Also how can I host a asp.net website on local domain controlled server to be able to be accessed just locally by all users on the vlan/domain? Would it be easier to use SQL?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Access as the backend for a website. Use SQL Server (even one of the free editions if you have to), or MySQL, or one of those. Access is not designed for what you're proposing. As for how to connect to the database, and how to deploy everything to a server, you can find lots of documentation, tutorials, examples etc online discussing these things. We're not going to repeat them here. Ask us again when you have a specific issue with your attempt, rather than a "please do my research for me" request. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its likely no more difficult to use SQL server, or use an access back end. The asp.net code,and how you pull data from SQL server, or Access will be written near identical. If you plan to start with Access and THEN use SQL server, then I recommend you use the ODBC provider over that of oleDB providers, and also over that of the standard sqlprovider. The reason for this is performance is not really different, but by using ODBC, the you can just flip the connection from Access to SQL server, and few if any changes would be required to your code.

To run a web server, then you need to install + setup IIS on that server. (most server editions from 2012 etc. onward quite much can install + setup IIS on that server). Once setup, then that web server will be limited to your local network. You can then just point your browser to the server name as the url, or even the IP address.

So, you will have setup a web server on your network, and hopefully you have a relative recent server edition of windows available for this purpose. You can install IIS "express" edition on a non server edition of windows, but it usually not worth the hassle, especially if you have a actual server edition of windows available to host the web site.